# Quartz status job reporting

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

We need to monitor the status of quartz jobs by only having access to the database. Does quartz offer a way to achieve this?

Reading the documentation, in the Trigger class we have TriggerState which defines various states, ERROR and COMPLETE among others.

But during regular execution, the CompleteExecutionInstruction is always NOOP. It doesn't matter if I throw an exception or execute completely. I was expecting something like COMPLETE if I was successful or ERROR if I threw an exception.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 6):

Trigger state in no way reflects the last execution status of your job so you cannot expect the trigger state to be COMPLETE or ERROR.

If you want to monitor your jobs, I recommend that you look into the Quartz [JobListener](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/JobListener.html) interface. This interface allows you to intercept and process all job execution events that you may be interested in. For example, you may want to implement a job listener that stores the intercepted job execution events in a database and then you can query this database to obtain the last job execution status of your jobs etc.

You may also consider using an existing Quartz scheduler, job and trigger management and monitoring tool. I am the original author of [QuartzDesk](https://www.quartzdesk.com) which is one of these tools. QuartzDesk is a completely non-intrusive tool that does not require you to modify your application code in any way, and it can work with all types of Java applications and nearly all Quartz versions. There is a [public online demo](https://www.quartzdesk.com/try-purchase/request-online-demo-access) that you can register to, try and see for yourself if the tool satisfies your requirements. When it comes to monitoring, the QuartzDesk GUI displays a so-called health indicator next to each job and trigger. This indicator depicts the status (success, error, veto) of the last 10 job/trigger executions so you can quickly see if there are any jobs that failed recently etc. You can also access complete execution history of individual jobs and trigger. If you want to be notified of any job execution related event, you can create an execution notification rule that will send you a notification message (IM, SMS, email, Slack, HipChat, SNMP Trap, ...) when a configured condition is met. I am attaching a screenshot of the GUI showing job health indicators and the selected job's execution history.

[image: QuartzDesk GUI].